# How to change the display order in a Modelica package?

Tags: modelica, dymola

I built a few models in Dymola which all belong to a package, so how could change the display order in this package?
I know I could change the code in the text editor, but is there a method that allows me to do this by drag and drop in the package browser?

[image: of]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the context-menu via the right mouse button as shown below, or the keyboard shortcuts indicated there:

- CTRL + Arrow up to move it one upwards
- CTRL + Arrow down to move it one downwards
- CTRL + Page up to move it to the beginning of the package
- CTRL + Page down to move it to the end of the package

[image: Move models in Packages in Dymola]

Drag and drop is only supported to move the models from one package to another one (which can also be done using the `Rename...` entry from the context menu). There is no way to use drag and drop to reorder models in a package. The option named "Reorder using drag and drop" in the "Package Browser" tab is a bit misleading unfortunately.

BTW: When storing the package/models in folders/files, the order is stored in the `package.order` file within the package's folder. This can be edited manually as well.